# Evaluate $a(n) = \int_n^{n+1} \ln(1+\frac{|\sin{x}|}{x}) dx,$

Tags: calculus, functions, definite-integrals

So, the problem is like this : Given $a(n) = \int_n^{n+1} \ln(1+\frac{|\sin{x}|}{x}) dx,$ what is the limit of the sequence?

What i've applied to it is the first mean value theorem and i have reached to $\ln(1+\frac{|\sin{c}|}{c})$ with c $\in \Bbb [n,n+1]$ . After that i have evaluated the function and applied the squeeze theorem on the limit of
 $\ln(1+\frac{|\sin{c}|}{c})$ which got me to the answer lim a(n) as n->infinity =0 . I just wanted to check if i solved the problem correctly.

Comment: Yes: it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yep.
Rigorous answer will be like this : $|a(n)|\leq \max_{x\in(n,n+1)}|\ln(1+\frac{|\sin x|}{x})|\leq \ln(1+\frac{1}{n})\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ by continuity of $\ln$. (also $|\sin x|\leq 1$ and monotone increasing of $\ln$ is used)